# Update data on the form / tokens

Tags: javascript, php, ruby-on-rails, node.js, token

**What I wnat to build :** (first I must say that I havent got any accounts on my web site) For example I have form with input field that every one can fills, after that you can submit form and if everything correct you will forwarded to another page **!THAT CONTAINS!** url for your filed form (previous page with form that you filled)

Easy explaine : You fills form then click submit button if all OK go to another page that contains button with url to your filed form (for example if you want to fix some data on it)

**PROBLEM :** How to build this, if I havent got users with their own form.
I have heard about **tokens** but never worked with them. What can I do ?

Can someone help me ? Forward me to the right way

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you imagine that your question could be answered by an article or even a whole book you are asking too much. What you are asking is the basics of web development in any language or framework. Pick one and do some beginner tutorials (don't ask us on SO for recommendations, we deal with answers - not recommendations).  http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I read rules, and i know that my question is to much, but what goind wrong with you if you cant help people because some rules tell you that, stackoverflow rules tell that you can not answer, but the main idea of stackoverflow is to help people like me, yep my question  
not exactly what you want to see, but if that is basic of web, you can give link to that inforamation, and I will not ask such questions so if u can help , try to do it first

Comment: Its not that we don't want to help. We care about StackoverFlow and close off topic questions to keep it from turning into a giant trash pile. We don't do tutorial recommendations as it works like a spam magnet.